# How to export Jar with Jfreechart library

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jar

I am looking to export a Java project into a Executable Jar file from eclipse.

I have tried to export from Eclipse a) as Jar b) as Executable Jar. There are Jfreechart libraries in project, although I check the option "export all referenced libraries" the UI run from exported Jar doesn't really draw the graph.

I tried adding Fat Jar into project "Referenced libraries" in Eclipse, no luck yet.

This is related to my previous question as well : [Provide/Export executable file to client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7585970/provide-export-executable-file-to-client)

Comment: I always export as "Runnable JAR File" and mark the option "package required libraries into generated jar". Have you tried to run the jar from cmd and see if the console show some exception?

Comment: I don't see any comments nor errors in command prompt. I am seriously confused what is happening.

Comment: what do you mean with "doesn't really draw the graph"?

Comment: Fat Jar is the solution. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author, in order to move it to the answer space)*.

Found the solution, Fat Jar helped me do this.

Comment: Hi David. I have moved your answer to the question space, but it is not very detailed, and I don't know if a future reader could make much use of it. I appreciate this is an old question, but I wonder if you could expand on this? I suppose we could just close the question, but it would be nice to capture some knowledge if we can.